# How to write a custom class loader to load classes from a jar?

Tags: java, classloader

I have the target to write custom class loader, which is needed for loading classes from some custom repositories, to implement hot deployment features and to allow unloading of classes. If you have experience with similar task, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a custom `ClassLoader` in your case, [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) should be enough, you simply provide an array of `URL` as parameter (corresponding to the folders of classes or jar files to include) to its constructor and eventually the parent class loader (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` could be a good candidate).

**NB:** As you intend to do hot deployment, make sure that you call `close()` on your `URLClassLoader` instance to properly release the resources.

Here is how you will then create dynamically an instance of a `Class` using reflection:

```
Class<?> myClass =  Class.forName(myClassName, true, myClassLoader);
Object myObject = myClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: I need for flexible control under the loading class process, where i can control this process, URLClassLoader is not appropriate for this target. Links in my answer solve my problems.

Comment: I've already created a project based on URLCL with very similar needs and it was enough https://github.com/essobedo/application-manager. It's not clear in your comment/question what is specfic in your requirements that prevents you to use it too